# class cSimulation' has no member named 'lastModuleIndex'

Tags: omnet++

I have converted a source code of LEACH protocol which was written in OMNeT 3.3. I converted it to OMNeT 4.5. But I found a error:

> class 'cSimulation' has no member named 'lastModuleIndex'

May be lastModuleIndex is deprecated. Could you please tell me the corresponding method in 4.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you can read at: https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/api/APIChanges.html

`cSimulation changes: lastModuleIndex() renamed to lastModuleId();`